# How do I replace a string in text file depending on value in matrix

Tags: powershell, matrix, replace

I am trying to replace a partial string from a line in a text file. For example, I am trying to replace `ABCD` with `Blah Blah - ABCD`:

**Input**

`12345,FOO FOO,ABCD`

**Desired Result**

`12345,FOO FOO,Blah Blah - ABCD`

I have set up a matrix (CSV file) to create a relation between the string I need replaced with the updated string, because I may not always need to replace `ABCD`:

**Example of Matrix**

```
Name1                                Name2                                                                           
-------------                        -------------                                                                           
ABCD                                 Blah Blah - ABCD  
EFGH                                 Blah Blah - EFGH
IJKL                                 Blah Blah - IJKL
```

So, to clarify, sometimes I may need to replace `ABCD`, `EFGH`, or `IJKL`. Hence, why I set up the matrix. How do I use PowerShell to dynamically replace the string in the current text line with `Name2` from the matrix I created?

**Where I'm stuck**

```
$str = #code to get string that needs to be replaced

Get-Content $txt_file | Foreach-Object {

   $_.Replace($str, #THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK. HOW DO I IMPLEMENT MY MATRIX)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.Replace(String, MatchEvaluator)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) from the [Regex class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-7.0).

Assuming your CSV file looks something like this (for column names I would recommend `Key` and `Value`, but its up to you):

```
Key,Value
ABCD,Blah Blah - ABCD
EFGH,Blah Blah - EFGH
IJKL,Blah Blah - IJKL
```

And assuming you have the following example lines stored in `$exampleLines` variable:

```bash
$exampleLines = @(
    '12345,FOO FOO,ABCD'
    '12345,IJKL,BAR'
    'EFGH,12345,BAZ'
)
```

In Windows PowerShell the code would look like this:

```bash
$map = @{}

$re = Import-Csv path\to\mapfile.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $map[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    [regex]::Escape($_.Key)
}

$re = $re -join '|' -as [regex]

$exampleLines | ForEach-Object {
    $re.Replace($_, { $map[$args[0].Value] })
}
```

If you need case insensitive matching of the keys then change:

```bash
$re = $re -join '|' -as [regex]
```

To:

```bash
$re = [regex]::new(
    $re -join '|',
    [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase)
```

In PowerShell 7+ the code is simpler, you can use [**Replacement with a script block**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-a-script-block). This method is also case-insensitive by default.

```bash
$map = @{}

$re = Import-Csv path\to\mapfile.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $map[$_.Key] = $_.Value
    [regex]::Escape($_.Key)
}

$re = $re -join '|'

$exampleLines -replace $re, { $map[$_.Value] }
```

Comment: Thank you! I will be away from this project for the remainder of today. Will take a look at this solution tomorrow. Appreciate it!