# Can you use a negative number in substring in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, substring

Can you use a negative number in the string length attribute for `Substring` in PowerShell? For example:

`$str.Substring($startPos, -3)`

I read that in PowerShell 7 reading backwards may have been added ("[negative values return the amount of substrings requested starting from the end of the input string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.3)") but it looked like that was for `Split`.

Currently, I cannot upgrade to v7. I am on v4. Is it possible to do this in Version 4?

**OR** is there another way to read backwards on a string in PowerShell v4?

**Example:**

I need to replace `ABCD`, but because of the commas and lack of consistent data points, it's very hard for me to find a consistent index *before* `ABCD`. Hence, why I use `LastIndexOf` to find the last comma. Now, I am hoping I can read backwards the length of `$replaceStr` from the last comma, if that makes sense. `$replaceStr.length` is what I was hoping to make negative.

```
$str = '12345,FOO FOO,ABCD,12351235'
$replaceStr = #code to get value of string that needs replaced
$str.Replace($str.Substring($str.LastIndexOf(',') + 1, $replaceStr.length), $Value)
```

**Import-Csv method (mentioned in comments)**

This is my PowerShell to import the CSV, replace `name`, and then `Set-Content` to the original file. When I `Set-Content` the CSV file's output is empty.

```
#gets all the full paths of each csv file
$files = (Get-ChildItem $path -Filter '*.csv').FullName

#loops through all found csv files
$files | Foreach-Object {
  #imports current csv file
  $csv = Import-Csv $_ -Header foo, foofoo, name, foobar
  
  #loops through csv 
  $csv | Foreach-Object {
    #replaces .name with $replaceStr
    $str.Replace($_.name, $replaceStr)
    #set content of csv file
  } | Set-Content -Path $_
}
```

Here is an example of my CSV file:

```
12345,FOO FOO,ABCD,12351235
54321,FOO BAR,ABCD,56785678
23232,FOO,ABCD,98765432
00000,FOO FOO BAR,ABCD,123456789
```

Comment: You definitely can't use a negative number with the `SubString` method but If you give an example on what you're looking to accomplish with might be able to help

Comment: @Santiago Squarzon, updated my answer with an example. Thanks!

Comment: Is your file a CSV by any chance? If so this might be easier using `Import-Csv` and then updating the property values

Comment: Turns out my file is a CSV, so I am trying your original suggestion. I am importing the CSV and utilizing the following code to try and replace the `ABCD` value. `$csv | Foreach-Object {$str.Replace($_.name, $replaceStr)} | Set-Content $file` but it sets the file content to only a list of all the changed `name`'s. How do I set the content of the file to include ALL the lines of the original CSV? @SantiagoSquarzon

Comment: Your CSV has proper headers? Could you add maybe 2 to 3 lines (including headers) as an example to your question

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I have added an example of my script and csv. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like your CSV dont have a header and see you're correctly using `-Header foo, foofoo, name, foobar`. While exporting them back after updating, are you looking to preserve this header or not?

Comment: I don't need the header after exporting

Comment: That update should cover it. Hope it helps. Please try this with some tests files before doing it with the real files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to not overcomplicate the code, you might find it easier if you transform your string into an array via splitting on `,` then updating the 2nd to last token and lastly joining it back with `,` as delimiter:

```bash
$str = '12345,FOO FOO,ABCD,12351235'
$tokens = $str.Split(',')
$tokens[-2] = 'myNewValue'
$str = $tokens -join ','
$str # 12345,FOO FOO,myNewValue,12351235
```

You're really close with your example treating the files as CSV, a minor update would fix the problem:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter '*.csv' | Foreach-Object {
    $csv = $_ | Import-Csv -Header col1, col2, col3, col4
    $csv | ForEach-Object {
        # update the value of this property
        $_.col3 = $replaceStr
        # then output the updated object
        $_
    } | ConvertTo-Csv |
        # here we're skipping the headers
        Select-Object -Skip 1 |
        Set-Content -LiteralPath $_.FullName
}
```

To update the value of a property since now you're dealing with objects due to `Import-Csv` you can simply refer to the property name to be updated and assign it a new value: `$obj.Property = 'mynewvalue'`. You would also need to convert these objects back to a CSV representation, for that you would be using `ConvertTo-Csv` and lastly skip the headers with `Select-Object` and save it back with `Set-Content`.

Comment: I'm so close lol! So, you helped me with my last question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75795088/how-do-i-replace-a-string-in-text-file-depending-on-value-in-matrix/75795248#75795248) and that is part of this lol. I did not include it in this question because I didn't think it mattered. However, I am using `$map[$args[0].Value]` in place of `$replaceStr`.  However, when I export my CSV, my script sets `col3` as literally "$map[$args[0].Value" instead of the Value I have set in my CSV matrix, if that makes sense.

Comment: seems like you're looking for `$_.col3 = $re.Replace($_.col3, { $map[$args[0].Value] })` @Crimp but I feel this should be part of a different question.

Answer (score 2):

`LastIndexOf` has an overload that starts at a given index as searches *backwards* toward the *start* of the string:

[`LastIndexOf(Char, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-8.0#system-string-lastindexof(system-char-system-int32))

> Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence of a specified Unicode character within this instance. The search starts at a specified character position and proceeds backward toward the beginning of the string.

So once you've found the ending `,` you can search from the position *before* it to look for the previous one:

```
$str = "12345,FOO FOO,ABCD,12351235";

# find the last ","
$end = $str.LastIndexOf(",");
# 18

# find the one before that
$start = $str.LastIndexOf(",", $end - 1);
# 13

# extract the result just to prove it's right :-)
$value = $str.Substring($start + 1, $end - $start - 1);
# ABCD
```

And to replace that string in the original you can do:

```
$replace = "WXYZ";

$result = $str.Substring(0, $start + 1) + $replace + $str.Substring($end);
# 12345,FOO FOO,WXYZ,12351235
```

In your specific case though, since the data is a CSV file it's probably better to use `Import-Csv` or `ConvertFrom-Csv` and let those cmdlets take care of all the complicated rules around quoted strings, line breaks in data, and other edge cases that would break the above `LastIndeOf` approach.

For example, if the original data were this:

```
12345,FOO FOO,ABCD,"1235,1235"
```

you'd get the wrong result because the last comma is part of the *data*, not the *syntax* so shouldn't be matched against.